# Help with PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Suppose i need to invoke a function (php) from inside a js function using AJAX, is the

following syntax correct:

```
$.post("phpReceivingFile.php", {func: (name: "james")}
```

....
....

Answer (score 4):

No, it won't work, you can't invoke specific php functions like that. I suggest sending a get parameter and inside your php do something like:

```
if($_GET['func'] == 'yourfunction') yourfunction($_GET['name']);
```

Comment: Tried sending it using GET, now how do i return true or false back to the page: for ex: i use true and false, will just returning true or false merely work

Comment: What js framework? You can't just return true or false, you're js will need to interpret the data coming back. JSON is probably the best way to do this. This is a different question, it's probably best to open a new question and asking about this with full code examples

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look [at this short php/ajax tutorial](http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-php.html) to see how you get the variables sent to a php script.